# Java: Multi Process of independant tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, multiprocessing

My question is quite simple:

I am working on Ubuntu and I wrote a program in Java (with Eclipse IDE).
The program does not read or write anything anywhere, it just make a lot of calculation and create many instance of home made classes.
The output of the program is simple: it write A, B or C in the terminal.(consider it as a random process)

I must run the program repetitively until I get 1000000 times A and count the number of times I got B and C. I did it, it works but it is too slow.

For example:output is:
"A:1000000
 B:1012458
 C:1458"

This is where I need your help:

I want to parallelize the program. I tried with multi-Threading but it did not work faster! So, while each simulation is independent, I want to make multi Processing. I would like, for example, create 10 Proccess and ask them to run the program until A appears 100000 times. (so 10 * 100000 = 1000000 as I want)
The problem is that I need to know the total number of B and C and for now I got 10 value of each.

How can I do? I tried the ProcessBuilder (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) but I do not understand how it works!

The only idea I have so far is to ask my program (with A till 100000) 10 times in the terminal with the command:
"java Main & java Main & java Main & java Main & java Main & java Main & java Main & java Main & java Main & java Main"
But then I must make the sum of the B and C occurrence MANUALLY. I am sure there is a better way to do this! I thought about creating 10 files with the value of (A), B and C and then read all of them and summarize them it is really a lot of work just to sum some integer isn't it?

Thank you forwards, I'm waiting for help :D

ps: To answer easily, let's consider I have a program named "prog" that take only int argument that represent the number of A I want to reach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parallelization makes sense only if you have multicore CPU. Run java.lang.Runtime.availableProcessors() to know how many threads you should run.

Then, running 10 batches of 100000 repetitions is not the same as running one batch with 1000000 repetitions, since the internal state of your application is changing, so think if parallelization is applicable at all in your case.

To know the total number of A,B, and C results just use AtomicInteger for all threads. Each time check if the count of A is less than 1000000.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a main class which launch your `prog` using one of the versions of [`Runtime.exec(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) method. By this you could use its [process' outputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29) to transmit to the main program the value each of your processes has computed.

Answer (score 0):

On a single machine, parallel processing is more efficient when using multiple threads as compared to multiple processes.

When running on a single-core/single-CPU system, however, parallel processing will only bring a small performance penalty but no performance benefit for pure calculations. - Yet, when for example multiple slow IO is involved, multi-threading may speed up the process after all.

For short: Multi-processing will always be *slower* than multi-threading.

Comment: "parallel processing is more efficient when using multiple threads as compared to multiple processes": Nowadays, almost every computer is multi processing. Mine have 4*2 core, so multu processing is quicker than multi threading

Comment: Sorry, but this is a misunderstanding: On multi-core machines, multiple *threads* within a single process are also allocated to the available cores by the OS; a single *process* can therefore run on multiple cores in parallel via multiple threads. However, the overhead, not only w.r.t. performance, incurred with managing a number of *threads* and their interactions *within* a single process is always **lower** than what is needed for the same number of *processes*.